# Creating multiple tabitems from tabitem template in WPF C# XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, tabitem

I read many tutorials from MSDN about WPF styling and datatemplating and contenttemplating but no success.
I need to make same TabItems in my TabControl and I made manually TabItem which i want to use as host for Style and ContentTemplate for other TabItems in TabControl

```
<TabItem Header="1.semestar">
    <Grid x:Name="GridSemestra">
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <ViewModel:PredmetVM/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100"/>
         <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <Grid.Children>
        <ListBox x:Name="PredmetiLW" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Predmeti}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Naziv}" />
                 </DataTemplate>
             </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         </ListBox>
         <ListBox x:Name="RadioLW" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Predmeti}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ocjena}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
             </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          </ListBox>
          <Label Content="Prosjek Semestra :" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
          <Label x:Name="_prosjekSemestra"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="F2" Content="{Binding _prosjek, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
          <Label Content="Ostvareni ECTS-ovi :" HorizontalAlignment="right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
          <Label x:Name="_ectsSemestra"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding _ectsovi, Mode=OneWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Grid.Children> 
   </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: What exactly is fixed and what is variable in this example? I mean, what can change from instance to instance and what should be in the template?

Comment: @meilke http://www.deviantpics.com/images/2013/09/26/ask.png 

the properties in red are only changing and i want to set them when i am creating instance of tabitem 

<TabItem  Header="1.Semestar" ItemSource="?"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you define a style for any `TabItem`. In the example I created a white border and a black background for the `Header` content of the `TabItem`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">

        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5" Margin="2">
          <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Black">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
          </Grid>
        </Border>

      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: how can i set up Header for each ItemTab in that control template ?
cause <TabItem Header="blablabla" /> isn't working cause this tabitem inherits header property from template ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want your items to render with same template set the ItemTemplate for your TabControl like below:

```
 <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyTabItems}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="GridSemestra">
                        <Grid.DataContext>
                            <ViewModel:PredmetVM/>
                        </Grid.DataContext>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition  MinWidth="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition  MinWidth="30"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <Grid.Children>
                            <ListBox x:Name="PredmetiLW" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Predmeti}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Naziv}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                            <ListBox x:Name="RadioLW" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Predmeti}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Ocjena}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                            <Label Content="Prosjek Semestra :" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <Label x:Name="_prosjekSemestra"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="F2" Content="{Binding _prosjek, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <Label Content="Ostvareni ECTS-ovi :" HorizontalAlignment="right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <Label x:Name="_ectsSemestra"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding _ectsovi, Mode=OneWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid.Children>


                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

Doing this, for all the items in property MyTabItems, TabItems will be generated

Comment: hmm thanks,probably i misunderstoodyou,
but I don't want to create new property MyTabItems and then bind to it, 
I just want reduce(stop) copy/paste of same code in Xaml for 6x TabItems which will look and behave similar except TabItem's Header property and children's property for ItemsSource.